# Reactjs user Authentication with firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase

i'm doing a user authentication system in Reactjs with firebase with google signin method,  as I think my code does not have any problem, but when I click in the button the Popup shows and close immediatly and the error in my console is:

FirebaseError: Firebase: Error (auth/unauthorized-domain).

I went to firebase console > Authentication > Sign-In-Method to authorize domain, and can't see where I can put my domain

Sorry my English it's not my first language

my code, I'm using vite to create react project

```
// Import the functions you need from the SDKs you need
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getAuth, signInWithPopup, GoogleAuthProvider } from "firebase/auth";

// Your web app's Firebase configuration
const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyBPbVyiVcN4K7cmMSo1QsPJQeIxZUZ7yCE",
    authDomain: "social-app-bc20f.firebaseapp.com",
    projectId: "social-app-bc20f",
    storageBucket: "social-app-bc20f.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "426481165558",
    appId: "1:426481165558:web:07720e6132e0d91c21b8d7"
};

// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const provider = new GoogleAuthProvider();

export const auth = getAuth();

export const signInWithGoogle = () => {
    signInWithPopup(auth, provider)
        .then((result) => {
            // ...
            console.log(result)
        }).catch((error) => {
            // Handle Errors here.
            console.log(error)

        });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

firebase console > Authentication > Settings +to authorize domain